# how to insert using linq to entity foreign key value?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a table (TestTable) for example:

```
ID
Name
Parentid (FK)
```

and I would like to insert a new record like ID(1) Name(Test) ParentID(5) FK. How can  insert a new record into TestTable with linq to entity?

```
var testTable = new TestTable();
testTable.ID = 1;
testTable.Name = "TestName";
testTable ...
```

thank you for the working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())//MyEntities name may differ
{
    var testTable = new TestTable();
    testTable.ID = 1;
    testTable.Name = "TestName";
    testTable.ParentTableReference.EntityKey = EntityKey("MyEntities.ParentTableSet", entityKeyValues);//Entity set name for parent table may differ

    context.AddObject("TestTableSet",testTable);//Entity set name for TestTable may differ
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```